# Collecting $_POST values from consecutive name values

Tags: php

I am using a for loop to generate 9 rows of a table with their name identifiers ascending according to the row.

```
<?php 
$x = 0;
for ($x=0; $x<=8; $x++) {


echo '<tr>';
echo '<td style="width:200px;"><input type="text" name="title' . $x .'"></td>';
echo '<td><input type="text" name="description' . $x .'"></td>';
echo '<td style="width:50px;"><input type="number" name="cost' . $x .'"></td>';
echo '</tr>';

} ?>
```

The HTML comes out clean and just the way I want it.

```
    <tr>
<td style="width:200px;"><input type="text" name="title0"></td>
<td><input type="text" name="description0"></td>
<td style="width:50px;"><input type="number" name="cost0"></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td style="width:200px;"><input type="text" name="title1"></td>
<td><input type="text" name="description1"></td>
<td style="width:50px;"><input type="number" name="cost1"></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td style="width:200px;"><input type="text" name="title2"></td>
<td><input type="text" name="description2"></td>
<td style="width:50px;"><input type="number" name="cost2"></td>
</tr>
```

Notice the "name" attribute is ascending thus making it easy to collect form data.
However, I am not sure how to use another for loop to create compound variables to align with the submitted html.
I want a loop to create a list of declarations ...

```
$form0 = $_POST['form0'];
$form1 = $_POST['form1'];
```

and so on without typing out 24 variable declarations.
Any help? :)

Comment: arrays are your friend.  `name="title[]"` or `name="title[n]"` where `n` is the number if you want to be more explicit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$formData = array();
for($i = 0; $i < 23; $i++)
{
   $formData[$i] = $_POST['cost' .$i]; 

}
```

This is a simple loop that will go through 24 times and collect your data for you and save it in an array

Answer (score 1):

You *can* do it that way, but as you are already beginning to see, that's a terrible way to go about it. Use arrays

```
<?php 
$x = 0;
for ($x=0; $x<=8; $x++) {


echo '<tr>';
echo '<td style="width:200px;"><input type="text" name="title[' . $x .']"></td>';
echo '<td><input type="text" name="description[' . $x .']"></td>';
echo '<td style="width:50px;"><input type="number" name="cost[' . $x .']"></td>';
echo '</tr>';

} ?>
```

Better yet, put them in a multi-dim array:

```
<?php 
$x = 0;
for ($x=0; $x<=8; $x++) {


echo '<tr>';
echo '<td style="width:200px;"><input type="text" name="row[title][' . $x .']"></td>';
echo '<td><input type="text" name="row[description][' . $x .']"></td>';
echo '<td style="width:50px;"><input type="number" name="row[cost][' . $x .']"></td>';
echo '</tr>';

} ?>
```

That way you can easily loop through them, eg.

```
foreach ($_POST['row'] as $row) {
  // do something with these:
  // $row['title']
  // $row['description']
  // $row['cost']
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A few possibilities..

### 1.

You could use a simple `for` loop and store them in separate variables..

```
for($i=0;$i<=8;$i++)
{
    $form.$i = $_POST['form'.$i];
}
```

### 2. ( *preferred way...* )

or store them in arrays..

```
$form_arr = array();
for($i=0;$i<=8;$i++)
{
    $form_arr[] = $_POST['form'.$i];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try  this, Use `title[]`

```
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td style="width:200px;"><input type="text" name="title[]"></td>';
    echo '<td><input type="text" name="description[]"></td>';
    echo '<td style="width:50px;"><input type="number" name="cost[]"></td>';
    echo '</tr>';
```

To get the POST values,

```
 foreach($_POST['title'] as $key=>$title){

    echo $title;
    echo $description = $_POST['description'][$key];
    echo $cost        = $_POST['cost'][$key];

 }
```